# How to grab read-write-lock without releasing it in Lisp?

Tags: multithreading, lisp, ccl, readwritelock

I'm using Clozure CL to write an app. In the app, I need to write several files, so I made a read-write-lock for each file.

Now I'm trying to write a quit function. It checks whether all the file writings are complete and then quit. Basically it works like below:

1. Grab all the files read-write-locks
2. Quit CCL

I read the [Clozure CL document](http://ccl.clozure.com/manual/chapter7.7.html), but can't find any function like grab-write-lock. I can only find "grab-lock", "with-read-lock" and "with-write-lock". 'grab-lock' won't work on read-write-lock, the other two will release the lock automatically. So how can I grab all the file read-write-locks (not release them) and quit the app?

Comment: I propose to ask very Clozure CL specific questions on its mailing list. See:  http://ccl.clozure.com

Comment: Why would you want to hold the write locks after your program exits? Won't they be released upon program termination?

Comment: "'grab-lock' won't work on read-write-lock"  Can you show some code that illustrates what you mean?

Comment: Alright @JoshuaTaylor. `(setq a (make-read-write-lock)) (grab-lock a)`. This will get a error "The value #<READ-WRITE-LOCK [ptr @ #x21F1BC80] #x302013E0964D> is not of the expected type CCL::RECURSIVE-LOCK."

Comment: @WiseSimpson Thanks!  I'm not much of a Clozure user, so it wasn't obvious to me that a read-write-lock wouldn't be a CCL:LOCK (as the documentation specifies).  Did the macroexpansion I provided in an answer help at all?  It looks like the functions there would provide what you need…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not all that familiar with Clozure CL's locking mechanisms, but I think that some macroexpansion can illustrate at least one way to do this:

```
CL-USER> (pprint (macroexpand-1 '(with-write-lock (my-lock)
                                  do-something)))

(CCL::WITH-LOCK-CONTEXT
  (LET* ((#:G350 (MAKE-LOCK-ACQUISITION))
         (#:G351 MY-LOCK))
    (DECLARE (DYNAMIC-EXTENT #:G350))
    (UNWIND-PROTECT
        (PROGN
          (CCL::WRITE-LOCK-RWLOCK #:G351 #:G350)
          DO-SOMETHING)
      (WHEN (CCL::LOCK-ACQUISITION.STATUS #:G350)
        (CCL::UNLOCK-RWLOCK #:G351)))))
```

I can't say whether this (using `ccl::with-lock-context/ccl::write-lock-rwlock`) is a *good* way to do this in your own code or not, but it's certainly *a* way to do it.

Comment: Thx! I agree using `ccl::write-lock-rwlock` is a way. I wonder if there is another 'official' way?